# Using Workspace variables in a GUI matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, workspace, matlab-guide

I have a workspace called **finalnet**. Inside the workspace i have a neural network called **net**. and I want to use the network in one of the functions in my GUI.

Is there a way to do that?

I tried to use  **evalin** function : `network = evalin('finalnet','net')`

but i get this error:

> Error using evalin Unknown command option.

Comment: I don't know anything about neural networks but could you try using `setappdata` and `getappdata` with your network?

Comment: @Benoit_11 all i want is to call the network basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the wording of your problem it sounds like `finalnet` is a previously stored workspace such that `finalnet.mat` is located in some directory. Let's assume the current directory.

In this case you need to `load` the workspace into your GUI. Assuming that's in some random callback function, you want to call `load finalnet` or `load('finalnet.mat')`. Now that the workspace is locally available to your callback function you may access your `net`.

If you call `load finalnet` before you run your GUI then you would need to access `net` using `net = evalin('base','net')` inside your function. If you make any changes to `net` or other variables in the base workspace and you want those changes maintained even after exiting the GUI then you must call `assignin('base','net')`, or whichever variable you changed.

Comment: This is helpful, won't we need to load the workspace every time a function is called in the GUI? Is there a way to load the workspace once and then use the variables within each of the GUI functions?

Answer (score 1):

You have something wrong here. As far as i know, there are only following types of Matlab workspace:

1. Base workspace:

   - Store variables which you created directly from Command Window, or using `assignin('base', 'varname', value)`
   - You can access base workspace's variables from anywhere with `var = evalin('base', 'varname')`, or use them directly from Command Window
2. Function workspace:

   - Each function creates its own workspace when it is being launched. It is separated with base workspace. Within this function, you can still access the base workspace variables as mentioned in 1)
   - There is no way to access the function workspace variables from Command Window unless you call the function
   - If your function (supposed `test1`) calls another function (supposed `test2`), within function `test2` you can access `test1`'s workspace variable by `var = evalin('caller', 'varname_in_test1_workspace')`. If you want the function `test2` to use the variables in `test1`'s workspace, pass them as input arguments for `test2`
3. Global workspace:

   - Store variables that can be used (shared) by multiple workspaces.
   - You must declare them using `global varname` in all workspaces that you want to use. (i.e in both functions `test1` and `test2`, with same `global varname` command, even in Command Window (base workspace) if you want to access the variable from Command Window)

Back to your question: I believe there is no way to have a workspace called `finalnet` in Matlab. You got error because there is no such `finalnet` workspace in Matlab. You might misinterpreted between the `.mat` file which you got by saving your base workspace variables last time and the workspace itself. So probably you need to load the the `.mat` file at first, the variables inside will be loaded to Matlab's base workspace, and then you can access them from your functions as you want.